Is my proof valid for this Saccheri quadrilateral?
A Saccheri quadrilateral is a quadrilateral $ABCD$ such that $AB \cong CD$, and $\angle ABC$ and $\angle BCD$ are both right. I was asked to prove that $\angle BAD \cong \angle ADC$.
Note: Do not assume the parallel postulate.
Is my following proof valid?
Construct $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle BCD$. $\triangle ABC \cong \triangle BCD$ due to SAS theorem. Let $E$ be the point of intersection between $AC$ and $BD$. It follows that $AE \cong ED$. This means that the resulting triangle $\triangle AED$ is isosceles. The sum of the angles of the right triangles and isosceles triangle, $\angle BAC +\angle DAE \cong \angle BDC + \angle ADE$ $\therefore \angle BAC \cong \angle BDC$
Still new to proof writing, let me know if this is valid.

To re-order and clarify the argument somewhat:

Since by SAS $\triangle ABC\cong\triangle BCD$, then $\angle DBC\cong\angle ACB$, and $\triangle BEC$ is isosceles. Therefore$$AC-EC=DB-EB$$making $\triangle AED$ isosceles, and$$\angle EAD\cong\angle ADE$$Therefore$$\angle BAC+\angle EAD\cong\angle BDC+\angle ADE$$that is$$\angle BAD\cong\angle ADC$$
